# iOS 8 Exchange Server DeviceId

Tags: ios8, exchange-server, mdm

Exchange Server's DeviceId could be predicted by concatenating "Appl" and serial number for iOS 7 and lower. This technique allows adding rules for a device under iOS even if device is not connected to Exchange Server. But built-in email application generates some new 26-digit DeviceId in iOS 8.

Is there any way to get this new 26-digit iOS 8 DeviceId using serial number, uuid, IMEI, etc.?

Now it's impossible to automatically add a rule for a device by DeviceId beforehand because concatenating "Appl" and serial number does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but it will give you a start.

In iOS 7, Apple employed a new ID type to register in ActiveSync:  **EASDeviceIdentifier**

This is randomly generated, and seemingly impossible to guess ahead of time.  This identifier is the new default ID given to ActiveSync at signup in iOS8.

Source:  [a blog!](http://www.netzgoetter.net/internet/blogs/netzgoetter.nsf/dx/traveler-ios-8-why-you-should-update-your-servers.htm?opendocument&comments)

For iOS, I would suggest implementing management profiles and controlling **the device** more holistically, rather than trying to predict a device ID and enabling EAS for a specific handset.  Of course, I know nothing about your environment and couldn't say whether that approach is really appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Getting EASDeviceIdentifier in MDM Device info should work!